# Elasticsearch conditional score adjustment

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have several documents in my elastic search index which have the following fields:

```
"name": document name
"booster": score booster value
```

But the booster field is not present in all of the documents.
Then, I made a simple query

```
query.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", searchKey));
```

which gives each document a certain relevancy score. I then use a script to boost each document's score with the booster attribute (when it existed) with the following script:

```
String script = "if (doc.containsKey('booster')) {_score * doc['booster'].value;} else {_score * 1.0;}";
ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder scoreFunction = ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction(script);
FunctionScoreQueryBuilder finalQuery = new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder((QueryBuilder) query, scoreFunction);
```

However, this resulted in only the documents containing the booster field getting an actual score, while everything else received a score of 0. Is there a reason why the scoring of the documents without the booster field becomes 0?